# Last partition taking very long time to save into S3 bucket spark RDD

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, rdd

this is how currently we are persisting RDD to S3

```
  private void saveResult(Config jobConfiguration, SparkContext sparkContext, JavaRDD<Row> rowJavaRDD) {
    final Persister persister = new PersisterBuilder()
      .withRdd(rowJavaRDD)
      .withSparkContext(sparkContext)
      .withAwsCredentialsFile(jobConfiguration.awsCredentialsFile)
      .withCacheEnabled(jobConfiguration.cacheDataBeforeSave)
      .withJsonOutput(jobConfiguration.saveAsJson)
      .withSaveMode(jobConfiguration.saveMode)
      .buildForOutputPath(jobConfiguration.outputPath);
    persister.save(jobConfiguration.outputPath);
    persister.clean();
  }
```

I have 1000 tasks and 984 tasks finishes very quickly within 20 minutes but last 16 takes forever to complete or  never completes.

to be very specific this is how we write to S3

```
   dataFrameWriter.option("header", "true")
      .partitionBy("year", "month","submitDate");
```

So it creates folder with Year and then Month and for every date .
I am running job between 1st Sept to 18 Sept and that's why last 16 Tasks takes very long time.
Inside 1St Sept folder i see many files created that's good but i can not other folders created for 2nd Sept or others .
Is there any way i can improve this ?

Shuffle Read: 1258.5 GB / 61804285

How can we improve the task so that writing into S3 will be faster?

Update :
This is how we save partition
Do you suggest to increase the partition by adding date filed to it ?
Will it help distribute load ?

```
    final StructType schema = DataTypes.createStructType(fields);

    DataFrame dataFrame = SQLContext.getOrCreate(sparkContext)
      .createDataFrame(rdd, schema);

    if(cacheDataBeforeSave)
      dataFrame = dataFrame.persist();

    DataFrameWriter dataFrameWriter = dataFrame
      .write();

    if(saveMode == Config.SAVEMODE.OVERWRITE) {
      System.out.printf("Overwriting data in '%s'%n", path);
      dataFrameWriter = dataFrameWriter.mode(SaveMode.Overwrite);
    }else {
      System.out.printf("Appending data to '%s'%n", path);
      dataFrameWriter = dataFrameWriter.mode(SaveMode.Append);
    }

    dataFrameWriter.option("header", "true")
      .partitionBy("year", "month",,"submitDate");

    if(saveAsJson)
      dataFrameWriter.json(path);
    else
      dataFrameWriter.parquet(path);
  }

  @Override
  public void clean() {
    persisterHelper.clean();
  }
}
```

Comment: What package is PersisterBuilder from?

Comment: PersisterBuilder seems to be your own code, right? maybe you can show the code here...

Comment: @OluwafemiSule I have updated question :Do you suggest to increase the partition by adding date filed to it ?
Will it help distribute load ?

Comment: @jgp  I have updated question :Do you suggest to increase the partition by adding date filed to it ?
Will it help distribute load ?

Comment: You seem to be using a rather old version of Spark like 1.6 maybe? It should not affect us that much, but we never know. Can you output the number of partition before you write? Maybe they are not balanced (as in equal in size)?

Comment: @jgp That's true but when i have used date in partition i see job is progressing but getting `Your socket connection to the server was not read from or written to within the timeout period. Idle connections will be closed` error and job failed